# Using START /wait with MozBackup batch scripts

Tags: windows-7, batch, script

**OS: Windows 7 64-bit**

I have three batch files.

1. FirefoxBackup.bat
2. ThunderbirdBackup.bat
3. Firefox_Thunderbird_Backup.bat

The script inside `Firefox_Thunderbird_Backup.bat` is shown below:

```
@echo off
@echo Welcome to Firefox and Thunderbird Automated Backup!
CALL "D:\Scripts\FirefoxBackup.bat"
CALL "D:\Scripts\ThunderbirdBackup.bat"
```

The script inside `FirefoxBackup.bat` file is very similar to `ThunderbirdBackup.bat`. Kindly see Firefox backup batch script below:

```
@echo off
@echo Firefox backup will begin shortly!

echo.
@echo Deleting old Firefox backup file(s)...
@echo off
DEL /F "D:\Mozilla Products Backups\Firefox*.pcv"
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK

echo.
@echo off
@echo Firefox is quitting...
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK

@echo off
@echo off tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe" | find /i "firefox.exe" >nul && ( taskkill /f /im firefox.exe /T )
TIMEOUT /T 3 /NOBREAK

echo.
@echo Firefox backup is in progress!
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MozBackup\MozBackup.exe" "D:\Scripts\Default.firefoxprofile"
TIMEOUT /T 15 /NOBREAK

echo.
@echo Firefox backup successful!
echo.

@echo Firefox has re-launched.
echo.
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

The part I'm interested in is:

```
START "" "C:\Program Files\MozBackup\MozBackup.exe" "D:\Scripts\Default.firefoxprofile"
TIMEOUT /T 15 /NOBREAK
```

**Explanation on the above code snippet:**

MozBackup.exe is started along with a parameter. This parameter is the `Default.firefoxprofile`file which MozBackup understands, and can be manually edited as per the [instructions here](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/command-line-backup.php).

**Intentions:**

**I'd like to get rid of the manual waiting time (15s) and make use of** `START /wait`. This way, Firefox re-launches only after Mozbackup finishes executing. I am not sure how to go about this considering there are already 3 parameters, namely `""`, `C:\Program Files\MozBackup\MozBackup.exe`, and `D:\Default.firefoxprofile`. Is it possible to achieve that at all anyway?

Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think you can't use more than 3 parameters with Start?

Comment: I tried. It didn't work and I deduced that maybe I'm passing too many parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was much simpler than I expected. I just needed to use the /W switch. I noticed that the /WAIT switch does not work.

Here's the solution:

```
START /W "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MozBackup\MozBackup.exe" "D:\Scripts\Default.firefoxprofile"
START /W /B "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

What happens now is that Firefox will re-launch *only after* MozBackup has finished executing. I will also apply this to Thunderbird's backup script. Thank you for reading and I hope this backup script is useful to someone in the future :)

[Reference](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)